# How do i handle nested tabcontrol SelectionChanged event?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, event-handling

`TabControl` are nested as follows:
**MainWindow.XAML**

```
<TabControl SelectionChanged="Details_SelectionChanged" SelectedIndex="1"  x:Name="Details" >
     <TabItem Header="STATUS"   x:Name="Tab_STATUS">

        <TabControl SelectionChanged="Details_SelectionChanged"  x:Name="StatusSubMenu" >
            <TabItem  Header="CPU" x:Name="Tab_STATUS_CPU">
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem  Header="IO" x:Name="Tab_STATUS_IO">
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>

     </TabItem>

    <TabItem Header="SETTINGS"   x:Name="Tab_SETTINGS">
        <TabControl SelectionChanged="Details_SelectionChanged"  x:Name="SettingsSubMenu" >
            <TabItem  Header="CPU" x:Name="Tab_Settings_CPU">
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem  Header="IO" x:Name="Tab_Settings_IO">
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </TabItem>

</TabControl>
```

I Have an event handler **Details_SelectionChanged** 

**MainWindow.XAML.cs**

```
private void Details_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {


    }
```

I need to  identify each nested `TabControl` and `Tabitem` in order to invoke respective functions associated to it.How do i do it?Pleas Help.

Comment: What information do you need in the event handler exactly?

Comment: As TabControl is being nested within a TabItem, I need to know which Tab item is being selected and from which TabControl?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void Details_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsLoaded)
    {
        TabItem tabItem = e.AddedItems[0] as TabItem;
        TabControl tabControl = sender as TabControl;
        tb.Text = "Selected" + tabItem.Name + " in control " + tabControl.Name;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```